# Angular nested repeats, how to check how many levels down (prevent more than x levels of repeat)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an some nested ng-repeats using an angular drag and drop directive (https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists) and I am trying to look for a way to stop user from dragging in more than 3 levels. So I can do this with their drop callback, however I am not sure how to access the information of how many levels down I am inside the repeat.

So here is the HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-6 nestedDemo">

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="list.html">
            <ul dnd-list="list"  dnd-drop="dropCallback(event, index, item, external, type)">
                <li ng-repeat="item in list" dnd-draggable="item" dnd-effect-allowed="move" dnd-moved="list.splice($index, 1)" ng-include="item.dragType + '.html'">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </script>

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="unit.html">
            <div class="container-element box box-blue">
                <h3>Unit</h3>
                <div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="list in item.subModules" ng-include="'list.html'" ></div>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </script>

        <script type="text/ng-template" id="module.html">
            <div class="item">{{item.result.name}}</div>
        </script>

        <h3>Selected Modules</h3>
        <div class="eit-card col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div ng-repeat="(zone, list) in templateStructure">
                    <div class="dropzone box">
                        <div ng-include="'list.html'"></div>
                    </div>
                </d>v>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The main problem is with the unit.html - I would don't want it to allow another unit to be able to be dragged into it if it is the third level down of unit(s).

I was trying to use the `dnd-drop="dropCallback()` to access the dropped item, but it has no indication of current repeat level (or access to $parent). I have also tried something like this

```
  <div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="list in item.subModules" ng-include="'list.html'"ng-if="checkUnitLevel(item)"></div>


 $scope.checkUnitLevel = function(item) {
   //if has 3 parents return false?
   console.log(item);
  }
```

The log does not seem to fire, so I think I have the incorrect logic for this. I may just be approaching this incorrectly. Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So if anyone runs into this problem, I have devised a solutions. Alternatively - if there are any other and/or better ways of doing this it would be great to hear them!

I used the drop callback that that drag and drop library has built into it

```
<my-html-element dnd-drop="dropCallback(event, index, item, external, type)" >
```

then in the controller I call the model like so from the drop call back

```
 $scope.dropCallback = function dropCallback(event, index, item, external, type) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $scope.templateStructure.checkLevels();
            }, 500);
            return item;
        };
```

The `$scope.templateStructure` is the current instance of the model. The only thing I don't like about this is having to put the time out so I can return the item first so it is actually in the list so I can then check the levels.

The function on the model looks like this.

```
  function checkLevels() {

                function checkForUnits(unit) {
                    if (unit.dragType === 'unit') {
                        unit.allowedTypes = ['unit', 'module'];
                        return unit;
                    }
                }

                function checkIfUnit(item) {
                    if (item.dragType === 'unit') {
                        item.allowedTypes = ['module'];
                    }
                }

                function tooDeep(level) {
                    return function(nodes) {
                        if (level === 2) {
                            checkIfUnit(nodes);
                        } else if (level >= 1) {
                            _.map(_.filter(nodes.subModules[0], checkForUnits), tooDeep(level + 1));
                        } else {
                            _.map(_.filter(nodes, checkForUnits), tooDeep(level + 1));
                        }
                    };
                }

                tooDeep(0)(this.template);
            }
```

So as you can see I swap the `unit.allowedTypes` depending how deep it is inside the list. I use that on my ng-repeat on the ui with the drag and drop plugin's `dnd-allowed-types` like

```
 dnd-allowed-types="list.allowedTypes"
```

This seems to work great for me. I am certainly open to criticisms or suggestions! I hate to answer my own question but maybe someone will run into this problem as well and this will hopefully help. Thanks!